# Динамическое добавление формы в Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь написать собственное приложение для тестирования студентов. И возникает проблема с добавлением динамических полей. Все отображается, но при нажатии на "+", никакие поля не добавляются, но и ошибок не выдает. Помогите с данной проблемой, пожалуйста.

Смотрела этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax

А так же брала материал https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0

Через pip установила jQuery, Ajax. И добавила это в INSTALLED_APPS, но это прошло как-то бесследно и бесполезно.

***forms.py***

```
class TestModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tests
        fields = ('title', 'text' )
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5, 'cols': 20}),
            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5, 'cols': 20})
        }
QuestionFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Questions,
    fields=('title', ),
    extra=1,
    widgets={
        'title': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5, 'cols': 20}),
    }
)
```

***views.py***

```
def createtest(request):
    template_name = 'blog/create_tests.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        testform = TestModelForm(request.GET or None)
        formset = QuestionFormset(queryset=Questions.objects.none())
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        testform = TestModelForm(request.POST)
        formset = QuestionFormset(request.POST)
        if testform.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            # first save this book, as its reference will be used in `Author`
            test = testform.save()
            for form in formset:
                # so that `book` instance can be attached.
                question = form.save(commit=False)
                question.test = test
                question.save()
            return redirect('tests')
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'testform': testform,
        'formset': formset,
    })
```

***create_tests.html***

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row center">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <h2>Create new test</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row spacer">
        <label>{{testform.title.label}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            {{testform.title}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
    <div class="row form-row spacer">
            <label>{{form.title.label}}</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                {{form.title}}
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="row spacer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_js %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
            var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
            var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
            if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
            if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
            if (el.title) el.title = el.title.replace(id_regex, replacement);
        }
        function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
            var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
            var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
            newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function() {
                var title = $(this).attr('title').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
                var id = 'id_' + title;
                $(this).attr({'title': title, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
            });
            newElement.find('label').each(function() {
                var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
                if (forValue) {
                    forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
                    $(this).attr({'for': forValue});
                }
            });
            total++;
            $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
            $(selector).after(newElement);
            var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:last)');
            conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
                .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                .removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
                .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
            return false;
        }
        function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
            var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
            if (total > 1){
                btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
                var forms = $('.form-row');
                $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
                for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
                    $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function() {
                        updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
                    });
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        $(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'form');
            return false;
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            deleteForm('form', $(this));
            return false;
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Открывок из ***models.py***

```
class Tests(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название теста', max_length=200, unique=True)
    text = models.TextField('Описание теста')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tests-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Тест'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Тесты'


class Questions(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Вопрос', max_length=200, unique=True)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Tests, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.answer_set = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вопрос'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Вопросы'

    def user_can_vote(self, user):
        user_votes = user.vote_set.all()
        qs = user_votes.filter(test=self)
        if qs.exists():
            return False
        return True

    @property
    def get_vote_count(self):
        return self.vote_set.count()

    def get_result_dict(self):
        res = []
        for choice in self.choice_set.all():
            d = {}
            alert_class = ['primary', 'secondary', 'success',
                           'danger', 'dark', 'warning', 'info']

            d['alert_class'] = secrets.choice(alert_class)
            d['answer'] = choice.choice
            if not self.get_vote_count:
                d['percentage'] = 0
            else:
                d['percentage'] = (choice.get_vote_count /
                                   self.get_vote_count) * 100

            res.append(d)
        return res

class Answers(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Ответ', max_length=400, unique=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ответ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ответы'

    @property
    def get_vote_count(self):
        return self.vote_set.count()
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста файл с моделями

Comment: @Даниял готово!